# Regular expression find between numbers and comma

Tags: java, regex

I have an example set of strings
there is a need to separate them and get

```
 55B/2, --> B/2
 171-1, --> -1
 6"C",  --> "C" 
 26D,   --> D
 8/1,   --> /1
 83,    --> null/empty
```

I tried with this pattern, but the result is not quite the same
([A-Za-z/"-])([0-9-/"A-Za-z]+?)(?=,)

Comment: if you are able to explain more precisely what the input strings are like and what you would like to match, we can help better. And maybe you see why your own regexp is failing. Do input  strings always start with digits? What if it is like 'AB83/2,"?

Comment: `^[0-9]+([^0-9][^,]*),` Refer to https://regex101.com/r/tVfn8h/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RegEx is correct but you need little change in regEx.

In your RegEx, replace + with *.

Below Java Standalone code:

```
public class ExpMatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] examples = {"55B/2,", "171-1,", "6\"C\",", "26D,", "8/1,", "83,"};
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z/\"-])([0-9-/\"A-Za-z]*?)(?=,)");

        for (String example : examples) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while (matcher.find()) {
                sb.append(matcher.group());
            }
            String result = sb.toString().isEmpty() ? "null/empty" : sb.toString();
            System.out.println(example + " --> " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
55B/2, --> B/2
171-1, --> -1
6"C", --> "C"
26D, --> D
8/1, --> /1
83, --> null/empty
```